# Does staging buffer have better performance than host visible and host coherent buffer if an application constantly do buffer streaming?

Tags: vulkan

by **Buffer streaming** i mean the vertex data are constantly updating every single frame.

i can understand how a staging buffer will be fast if it is static data, but what if the input vertices are constantly changing? does staging buffer still have the advantage over `host visible`  and `host coherent`

or should i just use staging buffer as a fallback when the host coherent memory isn't available.

also, i have another question, can `host visible` and  `host coherent` and `device local`  all get used together? what's the difference between `not specifying device local` and `specifying device local` in both cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staging buffers give you the ability to transfer data into device visible, host non-visible memory (i.e. discrete card GRAM).

Shared host-device buffer access without staging needs memory to be both device visible and host visible.

Impact of these two is really system dependent.

For integrated graphics and mobile graphics, there is generally no discrete GRAM. Nearly all available memory is therefore shared between the CPU and GPU, and therefore "host visible and device visible". On these devices there is no point using staging buffers unless you need layout changes (like texture upload/readback).

For discrete graphics, you have a discrete GRAM. If you want resources to live in GRAM then use staging because GRAM is not "host visible". If you want resources to live in system RAM then use "host visible and device visible". GPU access to system RAM will be slower than GRAM (requires travel over PCIe protocol). It is also normally a smaller capacity than GRAM (depends on the PCIe aperture size exposed by the device).

TLDR: YMMV, benchmark both speed and capacity on the devices you care about.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i think benchmark is probably the best option.

Comment: Hi!
You misinterpreted the spec. ANY memory you can use for buffers is "device visible" so it is entirely possible just use host accessible memory directly from shaders. https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-device Note that previous chapter talks more about Vulkan internal objects, not about buffers which OP asked about.

Please, correct your answer because it caused big confusion at least for me when I began to learn Vulkan.

Comment: Note that specification talks about HOST_COHERENT and HOST_VISIBLE memory in "Device memory" chapter, and tells that all "device memory" is accessible to hardware.

Comment: "It is entirely possible just use host accessible memory directly from shaders" possible, but can be quite slow if you have a discrete graphics card. Host accessible memory generally means pulling data over PCIe when the GPU wants to access it. Can also be limited in size, as the PCIe aperture size is usually smaller than the main graphics RAM (although has increased in recent generations).

Comment: If you have memory heap that is not device visible, and you want to allocate a buffer in to it, you need staging. So, I stand by my answer ...

Comment: "and tells that all device memory is accessible to hardware"

Yes, but not all device memory is accessible to the __host__, which is what the question is about.